# NetUseAdd returns error 67 or 87

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm calling the NetApi32.dll method `NetUseAdd`.
This is how:

```
USE_INFO_2 useinfo = new USE_INFO_2();

useinfo.ui2_remote = UNCPath;
useinfo.ui2_username = User;
useinfo.ui2_domainname = Domain;
useinfo.ui2_password = Password;
useinfo.ui2_asg_type = 0;
useinfo.ui2_usecount = 1;
uint paramErrorIndex;
returncode = NetUseAdd(null, 2, ref useinfo, out paramErrorIndex);
```

When calling this with `useinfo.ui2_remote = \\servername\dirname` it returns code 67 and when calling with `useinfo.ui2_remote = \\servername\dirname\` it returns code 87.

When I say it returns code...I mean that either it throws exception and `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` returns this error code, or the actual call to `NetUseAdd` returns it.

The weird thing is, that this method succeed when calling this with a path that **doesn't** have dub-folders, and fails when calling with a path that **has** sub-folders.

The calling machine is Windows server 2008, and the remote is a linux server (I'm not sure what version or distribution).

Any idea how can I successfully connect\use the remote resource without worry about the subfolder issue?

**edit**:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal struct USE_INFO_2
{
     internal LPWSTR ui2_local;
     internal LPWSTR ui2_remote;
     internal LPWSTR ui2_password;
     internal DWORD ui2_status;
     internal DWORD ui2_asg_type;
     internal DWORD ui2_refcount;
     internal DWORD ui2_usecount;
     internal LPWSTR ui2_username;
     internal LPWSTR ui2_domainname;
}

[DllImport("NetApi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern NET_API_STATUS NetUseAdd(
     LPWSTR UncServerName,
     DWORD Level,
     ref USE_INFO_2 Buf,
     out DWORD ParmError);
```

More info worth mentioned: the remote path that I'm trying to Add using NetUseAdd is a Huge storage (7 TB). A simple access with Windows explorer takes about 3-4 seconds to reach, but eventually it appears.

Comment: Show the line where you assign a value to `UNCPath`

Comment: `UNCPath = "\\\\servername\\somedir";`

Comment: What is the value of paramErrorIndex? When I have a \ as last char the error is 87 it returns 2  on my box. It returns 67 if I use invalid credentials Is your linux box domain joined? My linux server isn't so I have to enter the servername as the domain.

Comment: You said something about sub-folders. So are you saying that `@"\\server\dir"` works, but `@"\\server\dir\subdir"` doesn't? A weird idea, but you did say Linux ... what about something like `@"\\server\dir/subdir"`?

Comment: Regarding your @jimm first question: the other way around. `@"\\server\dir\subdir"` works, but `@"\\server\dir"` doesn't (if `subdir` exists under `dir`).

Comment: @jimm: Regarding the second one ,  I'm **not** interested in the subdir directory, I need the root directory.

Comment: @jimm: Do you think `@"\\server/dir"` should work?

Comment: These are basic low-level error codes.  67 = "Bad network name, 87 = "Invalid parameter".  With good odds that you are fighting this problem because your pinvoke declarations are incorrect.  We can't see them.

Comment: Edited the pinvoke declarations. I don't think this is a declarations issue, though. The reason: the method succeed with the same declarations **if the directory in** `useinfo.ui2_remote` has no sub-folders.

Answer (score 7):

I am not am expert on this topic but I was using something like:

```
@"\\10.22.15.14\C$\Inetpub\wwwroot\db\archive\"
```

and I got a error code 87,
then I changed the string to be

```
@"\\10.22.15.14\C$\Inetpub\wwwroot\db\archive"
```

and it worked. perhaps, it may work for somebody else.

Comment: This worked on the error "87" for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue and managed to find out the culprit - if using the source code from [Original Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43091/Connect-to-a-UNC-Path-with-Credentials) I noticed that it would only allow me to connect when not running visual studio as administrator (my default set up). Hope this helps someone else frustrated by this!

Answer (score 1):

I found that the folder path is case sensitive as there should be no trailing backslashes in the path, as mentioned before.

After I changed that it worked.

Comment: trailing backslashes was the issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue connecting to a Linux server. The solution that worked for me was to map a network drive from Windows manually using the login credentials first, this must create some internal configuration that then allowed connection using NetUseAdd. I only had to map the drive once.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an outdated P/Invoke signature as [described here](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Steeltoe/pull/329/files).

Old, wrong:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class NetResource
...
```

New, correct:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public class NetResource
...
```